# Типизация километров и миль для корректности расчётов

Tags: c#

Никак не могу поймать концепт.

Есть система учета расстояния перевозки грузов

```
void savePathToDb(stping cargold, int milesPath, int KmPath)
{
}

var id = "test";
var miles = 109;
var kilosl = 46;
var kilos2 = 86;
SavePathToDB(id, kilosl, miles + kilos2);
```

И у нас возникла проблема. Из за того что часть товаров возят по дорогам и меряют километрами, а часть по морю и меряют морскими милями, часто получается ситуация когда разработчики по ошибке путают мили с километрами и получают неверные данные.

Как нам используя знания о конструировании типов создать типизацию при которой такая ошибка будет невозможна?

Была мысль написать отдельные структуры для мили и километра как единицы. Но в этом случае всё равно можно будет присвоить некорректное значение. Буду рад любым подсказкам!

Comment: 1) измерять все в чем то одном, например в километрах 2) Если на входе что то, что не километры, то пеерводить в километры. Например `SaveToDb(id, Distance.MarineMilesToKm(miles))`

Comment: А почему в случае отдельных структур можно будет присвоить некорректное значение? Вы же сами определяете набор операций. Не создавайте `operator +` для миль и километров — и всё.

Comment: Ну а вообще, вопрос, наверное, в другом. Если у вас есть "путь" часть сегментов которого выражена в "милях", а другая часть в "километрах", вы можете хранить его просто как массив простых объектов-значений. Для пути надо реализовать две операции: "посчитать полную длину в километрах" и "посчитать полную длину в милях", и вызывать их.

Comment: Не нужно вандалить вопрос.

Comment: @insolor я выложил вопрос, который принадлежит другому автору. Нарушаю правила и хочу убрать исходник, пожалуйста, не правьте

Comment: Удаляя текст задания вы фактически нарушаете правила сайта. Без текста задания вопрос не имеет смысла, и к тому же без задания существующий ответ автоматически становится неправильным.

Comment: Если вы считаете, что нарушаете какие-то правила, оставляя вопрос в текущем виде, рекомендую поставить тревогу на вопросе, выбрать пункт "требует вмешательства модератора", в поле описать суть проблемы.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

У меня в проекте в аналогичных случаях делается как-то так:

Определяем типизированную длину. Чтобы не возникало соблазна сконструировать непонятно из каких единиц, прячем конструктор, вместо него выставляем наружу так называемые именованные конструкторы.

```
struct Distance : IComparable<Distance>, IEquatable<Distance>
{
    readonly double meters;
    private Distance(double meters) => this.meters = meters;

    const double metersInKm = 1000.0;
    const double metersInMile = 1609.344;

    public static Distance FromKilometers(double km) => new Distance(km * metersInKm);
    public static Distance FromMiles(double miles) => new Distance(miles * metersInMile);

    public double Meters => meters;

    public static Distance operator + (Distance d1, Distance d2) =>
        new Distance(d1.meters + d2.meters);

    #region Equals, GetHashCode and operator ==
    public override bool Equals(object? obj) => obj is Distance other && Equals(other);
    public bool Equals(Distance other) => meters == other.meters;
    public override int GetHashCode() => HashCode.Combine(meters);
    public static bool operator == (Distance left, Distance right) => left.Equals(right);
    public static bool operator != (Distance left, Distance right) => !(left == right);
    #endregion

    #region CompareTo and operator <
    public int CompareTo(Distance other) => meters.CompareTo(other.meters);

    public static bool operator <  (Distance left, Distance right) =>
            left.CompareTo(right) < 0;
    public static bool operator <= (Distance left, Distance right) =>
            left.CompareTo(right) <= 0;
    public static bool operator >  (Distance left, Distance right) =>
            left.CompareTo(right) > 0;
    public static bool operator >= (Distance left, Distance right) =>
            left.CompareTo(right) >= 0;
    #endregion
}
```

Теперь ваш метод `SavePathToDB` должен принимать на вход не `int`, а `Distance`.

При этом `Distance.FromKilometers(2) + Distance.FromMiles(1.5)` вполне работает и даёт верный результат, а вот `Distance.FromKilometers(2) + Weight.FromKilograms(3)` не компилируется.

---

Кода получилось много, так что если у вас в проекте много таких вот структур, имеет смысл воспользоваться кодогенерацией.

---

Кстати, в братском F# единицы длины с аналогичными свойствами (включая автоматическое создание производных единиц наподобие `m/s^2`) [встроены прямо в язык](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/units-of-measure).

Comment: У меня почему-то ругается на public модификаторы доступа в конструкторах From.. и пишет, что по обоим должен быть указан возвращаемый тип

Comment: @thepotion33 `public static Distance FromKilometers ...`

Comment: `HashCode.Combine(meters)` - почему не `meters.GetHashCode`?

Comment: @Qwertiy: по двум причинам: (1) для более лёгкого обобщения, (2) вроде бы `HC.Combine` [добавляет случайности](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/HashCode.cs,78), что хорошо.

Comment: @VladD, мутабельная структура? :/

Comment: @АндрейNOP: Вроде иммутабельная, а что?

Comment: @VladD, чем хорошо? Разработчики double о ней уже должны были позаботиться.

Comment: @VladD, посмотрите метод Add, он изменяет поля. Просто странно, обычно такого стараются избегать

Comment: @АндрейNOP: Подождите, у меня вроде бы нету метода `Add`. Если вы про `operator +`, то он тоже ничего не меняет. Единственное поле `meters` у меня объявлено как readonly.

Comment: @Qwertiy: с `double` как раз понятно, но неплохо было бы, чтобы `5.GetHashCode()` отличалось от `Distance.FromMeters(5).GetHashCode()`. В некоторых ситуациях это может пригодиться.

Comment: @VladD, да я не про ваш код :) извините, что ввел в заблуждение. Я про структуру HashCode, просто раньше её не видел

Comment: @АндрейNOP: А, ну да. Просто было бы как-то не очень, если бы расчёт хэшкода нагружал GC, вот они и сделали её структурой. Плюс есть статические перегрузки на случай, когда количество значений известно на этапе компиляции.